# What happens when a flush is performed while a script is executing?

Tags: php, mysql, flush

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html) it says FLUSH TABLES:

> Closes all open tables, forces all tables in use to be closed, and
>   flushes the query cache. FLUSH TABLES also removes all query results
>   from the query cache, like the RESET QUERY CACHE statement.

I don't quite understand from the above, what is the implication it has when a FLUSH TABLES is performed while a PHP script consisting of several queries is run. Suppose that I have an `UPDATE` query on TABLE A, followed by an `INSERT` query on TABLE B, followed by `mail()` and `header()` on a transaction page, would the INSERT query be deleted when FLUSH TABLES is performed while MySQL is running the UPDATE query?

Comment: There is little practical reason to use flush tables. But I don't think it should interfere with an existing transaction and only run once it can get lock. It would be pretty easy to test though.

Comment: @datasage, is flushing all tables with read lock unnecessary before a backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL will wait until the end of queries made before, and then it will execute FLUSH TABLES. The queries made after FLUSH TABLES will be enqueued and executed after FLUSH TABLES.

If nothing unusual happen, no queries will be lost.